# IQueryable where clause overriden in inherited class

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I would like to give an inherited class the opportunity to provide a where clause to my query. Is this possible?

```
    protected IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
    {
        return from e in pContext.Entities
               where e.StatusCode == "Published"

               //is there a way to add a dynamic where clause here?
               //I would like to ask the inherited class for it's input:

               && e.OtherColumn == "OtherValue" // <-- like GetWhere(e)?

               //without having to select the column

               orderby e.PublishDate descending

               select new EntityResult
               {
                   Name = e.Name,
                   Link = e.Link
               };
    }
```

Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a virtual method that can apply the extra where condition:

```
protected IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
{
    IQueryable<Entity> query = pContext.Entities
       .Where(e => e.StatusCode == "Published");

    query = ApplyWhereClause(query);

    return from e in query
           orderby e.PublishDate descending
           select new EntityResult
               {
                   Name = e.Name,
                   Link = e.Link
               };
    }

protected virtual IQueryable<Entity> ApplyWhereClause(IQueryable<Entity> entities)
{

}
```

In your deriving class you would then do this:

```
protected override IQueryable<Entity> ApplyWhereClause(IQueryable<Entity> entities)
{
    return entities.Where(/* insert your extra where clause here */);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this code compiled and worked the very first time. Just one question: is all of this still executed on the datasource or is it loaded into memory and then filtered?

Comment: It's funny that I never thought of splitting it up in the first method.

Comment: as long as you're working with `IQueryable`, nothing is executed in the database. Only when you call .ToList() or similar, or start `foreach`-ing over the results is the query actually executed against the database.

Answer (score 3):

Since you return an IQueryable the query will only be executed when the resources are used. So as long as it stays IQueryable it'll stay just the query.

With this knowledge you can simply apply the where on your function which returns IQueryable

like this:

```
myObject.GetEntities(myContextObject).Where(x => x.id == 5);
```

Since the OtherCOlumn isnt there as you mentioned you can change your default query to:

```
 protected IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
{
    return (from e in pContext.Entities
           where e.StatusCode == "Published"

           //is there a way to add a dynamic where clause here?
           //I would like to ask the inherited class for it's input:

           && e.OtherColumn == "OtherValue" // <-- like GetWhere(e)?

           //without having to select the column

           orderby e.PublishDate descending

           select e).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and then do the select in your extended where. Since it stays a query as long the return type stays IQueryable this won't make it slower

Comment: Thank you, but the resulting query does not include the OtherColumn attribute to select from. So when I apply the where clause afterward like .Where(er=> er.OhterColumn) the OtherColumn is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Where clause is an extension method, so you can't override it, but you can pass a dynamically constructed expression tree to the where clause and produce the desired results.
Have a look at this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to write this in Linq notation, as I always prefer to use Linq extension methods, but it would look something like this:

```
protected IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
{
    var q = pContext.Entities
        .Where(e => e.StatusCode == "Published");
    q = q.AddWhereCondition(q)
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.PublishDate)
        .Select(e => new EntityResult
           {
               Name = e.Name,
               Link = e.Link
           });
}

protected virtual IQueryable<Entity> AddWhereCondition(IQueryable<Entity> query)
{
    return query.Where(e => e.OtherColumn == "OtherValue");
}
```

or, by extracting the Where() condition as Linq expression:

```
protected IQueryable<EntityResult> GetEntities(ETBDataContext pContext)
{
    var q = pContext.Entities
        .Where(e => e.StatusCode == "Published")
        .Where(e => GetWhereCondition(e))
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.PublishDate)
        .Select(e => new EntityResult
           {
               Name = e.Name,
               Link = e.Link
           });
}

protected virtual Expression<Func<Entity, bool>> GetWhereCondition(Entity e)
{
    return e => e.OtherColumn == "OtherValue";
}
```